# WCF communication from c++ gSOAP or C++/CLI?

Tags: c++, wcf, c++-cli, gsoap

I have several unmanaged c++ programs that I use to do "heavy lifting" type operations.  I like to database certain information that these clients use.  In order to do this I created a WCF service which exposes my DAL to the database.  I then created a managed C++/CLI wrapper to call the web service from the native C++.  Would it be better to parse the WSDL using gSOAP and connect to the WCF service using SOAP?

Comment: IMHO the [Google protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) can be an option to serialize data between the native C++ code and the .NET code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++/CLI wrapper approach does have many advantages.  This does make a simple way to use all of the WCF tooling, with any transport mechanism, from within C++.  However, it does introduce a dependency on the CLR, which may or may not be acceptable.

Another option would be to use the [C++ REST API (aka Casablanca)](http://casablanca.codeplex.com/) to call the WCF service directly, using a pure native API.  This would require exposing the WCF service via REST.

Comment: Thanks for the link, very interesting.  I'm just wondering what the best way is going forward.  Is it worth while converting over the wrappers to use the REST API?  Is this a subtle hint from windows that this is the way things will be soon?

Comment: @Ben Using a REST API will allow just about any tech to connect - the C++ REST API provides a nice, clean, lightweight, portable (pure native) C++ library that's open source, so it's tough to beat.

Comment: Just a follow up on this.  The Casablanca library works great, and doing an MVC application in Visual Studio allows you to pretty quickly write RESTful services.  It is so much cleaner without the wrappers too.  Thanks for the answer!